# Trouble using PowerShell cmdlet

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I try and run this Script using Powershell ISC run as Admin:

```
 #Site URL
 $web = Get-SPWeb "http://cgprojects/sites/tfs";
 $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true;    

 #List Name
 $list = $web.Lists["Project Initiation"];

 # Iterate through all Items in List and all Workflows on Items.         
 foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
 foreach ($wf in $item.Workflows) {

 #Cancel Workflows        
 [Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager]::CancelWorkflow($wf);      
 }
 }
 $web.Dispose()
```

What I get is this result:

> The term 'Get-SPWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At line:2 char:18
>   +  $web = Get-SPWeb <<<<  "http://  ";
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-SPWeb:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException   Property 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' cannot be found on this object; make sure it
>   exists and is settable. At line:3 char:7
>   +  $web. <<<< AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true;
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (AllowUnsafeUpdates:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound   Cannot index into a null array. At line:6 char:21
>   +  $list = $web.Lists[ <<<< "Project Initiation"];
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Project Initiation:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray   Unable to find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager]: make sure that the
>   assembly containing this type is loaded. At line:13 char:51
>   +  [Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager] <<<< ::CancelWorkflow($wf);
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Share...WorkflowManager:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:16 char:14
>   +  $web.Dispose <<<< ()
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Dispose:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Mohammad mentioned, you need to load the SharePoint Snapin in order to avoid this error:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try running the command from SharePoint Management Shell? Seems like SharePoint Snapin is not loaded.